# Karma + RequireJS + AngularJS, shimmed scripts not loading in spec

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, karma-jasmine

While using **Karma + Jasmine + RequireJS + AngularJS**, I'm unable to load any of my shimmed scripts, for example **`angular-mocks`**, into the test specs. The file seem to be served all right, just doesn't work in the spec.

UPDATE Angular is global, and the corresponding shim doesn't affect it.

[image]

In `Karma.conf.js`, I'm including `angular-mocks` to be loaded by RequireJS:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '../../',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        {pattern: 'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', included: false},
        ...
        'test/euro-2016/main-test.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
        'main/main-euro-2016.js'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        '../../*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
})
```

};

The RequireJS shim in the Karma main file `main-test.js`:

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
            tests.push(file);
        }
    }
}

requirejs.config({
    // Karma serves files from '/base'
    baseUrl: "/base",

    paths: {
        "angular": "vendor/angular/angular",
        "angularMocks": "node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks",
        "jquery": "vendor/jquery/jquery.min",
        ...
    },

    shim: {
        "angular":      {
            exports:    "angular",
            deps:       ['jquery']
        },
        "angularMocks": {
            exports: "angularMocks",
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        ...
    },

    // ask Require.js to load these files (all our tests)
    deps: tests,

    // start test run, once Require.js is done
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

The spec file:

```
define(['angular', 'modules/euro-2016/app', 'angularMocks'], function(angular, app, mocks){
    console.log("ANGULAR", angular); // ok
    console.log("APP", app); // ok
    console.log("MOCKS", mocks); // undefined
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code that is installed by installing the NPM package `angular-mocks`, specifically the file `node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js`, here is what I see:

1. There is no mention of `angularMocks` anywhere in that code, therefore exporting `angularMocks` cannot work.
2. Conversely, the plugin installs itself as `angular.mock`. Early in the file there is the line:

   ```
   angular.mock = {};
   ```

   And then everything is added to `angular.mock`.

So you can remove your `exports` and access the plugin through `angular.mock`. This should work:

```
define(['angular', 'modules/euro-2016/app', 'angularMocks'], function(angular, app){
    console.log("ANGULAR", angular);
    console.log("APP", app);
    console.log("MOCKS", angular.mock); 
});
```

If you must have an `exports` for some reason (for instance if you use `enforceDefine`, which requires that all `shim` have `exports` values) you could set it to `angular.mock`.